# Firefox - Download files using external bash script

Tags: linux, firefox, bash, wget

Is possible to issue external bash script when files are being downloaded in Firefox? My goal is high customization. E.g. scripting something that will save files to specified folder based on extension could be trivial with bash and wget.

Related links that I have found, but unfortunately none solves my problem directly:

- [Calling bash script from firefox.](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=663377&start=0)
- [how-to-open-exe-with-javascript-xpcom-as-windows-run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6177583/how-to-open-exe-with-javascript-xpcom-as-windows-run)
- [how-to-run-a-local-exe-in-my-firefox-extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490713/how-to-run-a-local-exe-in-my-firefox-extension)
- [running-exe-in-firefox-why-do-i-get-an-error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6472435/running-exe-in-firefox-why-do-i-get-an-error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if Firefox supports hooks like these (I don't think so), but you can easily achieve this using [`inotifywait`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait) with the added advantage that since it would "listen" on a specific directory that this would work for several applications downloading files into this directory.

For an example you can see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16165494/612462) over on StackOverflow.

Comment: What a pitty, thanks for tip anyway. Have you any experiences with it?